# Slashed "male" symbol

Tags: symbols

For my thesis I need a symbol for neutered male (veterinary medicine) which is a mars symbol with a backslash superimposed. With the descriptions I found, it didn't work for my document. I'm using `scrartcl` as documentclass which I can't change because of my reference style.

Comment: could you show an example of how it looks like?

Comment: Isn't it simply `\not\Male` ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: @tohecz: Do you mean `\usepackage{wasysym}` together `$\not\male$`? In that case, it doesn't work very well because `\not` produces a forward slash, and the slash doesn't go through the symbol properly.

Comment: @pikatma -- is this a commonly used symbol (in veterinary medicine, it seems quite reasonable)? if so, can you cite a published example of its use?  i don't believe it's in unicode yet, but with a good citation, i can arrange to have it considered.

Comment: @Jake Yes, I meant it. I wasn't sure it works, that's why I didn't post an answer...

Comment: Not sure if it was intentional, but that's one appropriate title.

Answer (score 7):

Since the placement of tha backslash is not obvious from the description in the original question, I provide three options using TikZ (the last one suggested by **barbara beeton** in a comment):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\Nmale{%
  \tikz{\node[draw,circle,scale=0.5] (a) {};\draw[->] (a.45) -- +(45:4pt);\draw +(a.north west) -- +(a.south east);}}

\def\Nemale{%
  \tikz{\node[draw,circle,scale=0.5] (a) {};\draw[->] (a.45) -- +(45:4pt);\draw +([xshift=-1.5pt,yshift=1.5pt]a.north west) -- +([xshift=1.5pt,yshift=-1.5pt]a.south east);}}

\def\Neumale{%
  \tikz{\node[draw,circle,scale=0.5] (a) {};\draw[->] (a.45) -- +(45:4pt);\draw +([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=2.5pt]a.45) -- +([xshift=2.5pt,yshift=-0.5pt]a.45);}}

\begin{document}

\Nmale

\Nemale

\Neumale

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am now almost convinced that the backslash should cross only the arrow, so here are some options for male and female:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\Neumale{%
  \tikz{\node[draw,circle,scale=0.5] (a) {};\draw[->] (a.45) -- +(45:4pt);\draw[very thin] +([xshift=-0.5pt,yshift=2.2pt]a.45) -- +([xshift=2.2pt,yshift=-0.5pt]a.45);}}

\def\Neufemale{%
  \tikz{\node[draw,circle,scale=0.5] (a) {};\draw[->] (a.270) -- +(270:4pt);\draw[very thin] +([xshift=-1.9pt,yshift=-1pt]a.270) -- +([xshift=1.9pt,yshift=-1pt]a.270);}}

\begin{document}

\Neumale

\Neufemale

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thinking some more about this, it seems possible that the meaning of the symbol might be even more obvious if the slash crossed just the arrow.  but someone in the field would be able to comment with more authority.

Comment: @barbarabeeton your option makes sense; I've added it to my answer.

Comment: tiny niggle: length of slash looks good, but the visual effect is that it's closer to the arrowhead than to the circle.  (without claiming to be an expert) i think it would look clearer with the slash just a bit closer to the circle, maybe by the thickness of the slash.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, you're right; I've incorporated your suggestion to my updated answer (the slash is thinner and closer to the circle); I also added a female version. Thank you.

Comment: For the latter variant there is a unicode character: U+26A6 "male with stroke sign (= transgendered sexuality)".

Comment: Thanks for the answers. \Neumale is exactly what I needed. I only found the symbol today in unicode. It is sometimes used in veterinary medicine although only few people use latex in that field. My reviewer wanted the symbol to be changed in my doctoral thesis. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: Hi pikatma, welcome to the site! It's great that you found a solution! I think it would still be interesting if you could link to a published article where the symbol is used, as barabara beeton suggested in her comment on your question.

Comment: I wasn't really able to find a paper where it was used although I know that I've seen it before. The only site I found this symbol is Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols). Although I was looking for it in some journals I couldn't find it. If I do, I'll post it. But it looks like even in Veterinary Medicine it is not used that often.

Answer (score 6):

As you didn't state clearly how your symbol should look like, here are some examples (with and without TikZ). For the `\Neumale` symbol exists a Unicode character: [U+26A6](http://www.decodeunicode.org/u+26A6) 
[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\notmaleanymore{\leavevmode\kern.07em\raise.1ex\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{\bfseries\textbackslash}}\kern-.47em\male}
\def\neumale{\tikz{\node[inner sep=0pt] (male) {\male};\draw ($(male.south west)!.65!(male.center)$) +(135:.19em) -- + (-45:.2em);}}
\def\Neumale{\tikz{\node[inner sep=0pt] (male) {\male};\draw ($(male.south west)!1.20!(male.center)$) +(135:.15em) -- + (-45:.15em);}}
\def\neufemale{\tikz[baseline=-0.4ex]{\node[inner sep=0pt] (female) {\female};\draw (female.center)++(-.01em,.17em) +(135:.19em) -- + (-45:.2em);}}
\usepackage{fontspec} % needs XeLaTeX
\begin{document}
\noindent \male \notmaleanymore \neumale \Neumale \female \neufemale\\
\fontspec{LinLibertine_R.otf} % needs XeLaTeX
\char"2642                    % needs XeLaTeX
\char"2640                    % needs XeLaTeX
\char"26A6                    % needs XeLaTeX
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: some gender symbols]

Comment: the definition needs at least `\leavevmode` at the beginning to avoid an error if it happens to be used in vertical mode.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I've updated my answer.